# PythonInvalidSyntax: Hickup with class definition for data parsing?

Tags: python, parsing, syntax

I have been trying to parse a data file and thus have made this class , the problem i am encountering is that before placing my code inside a class it seemed to work fine. But since i want to make improvisations in the code to make it more efficient i want to define a class.Here's my code which worked fine before i placed inside my class and also "indented".

```
    class Athelete:
        # init function to create object instances.
        def __init__(self, a_name, a_dob, a_times=[]):
            self.name = a_name
            self.dob = a_dob
            self.times = a_times
# top3 function to display the 3 best times of my athelete times attribute
        def top3(self):
            return(sorted(set(sanitize(times)))[0:3])
# main_parser is reponsible for converting each line in the file
#to a list using ",(comma)" as the identifier to split.
        def main_parser(self, filename):
            try:
                with open(filename + ".txt", 'r') as james_list:
                    for each_line in james_list:
                        templ = each_line.strip().split(',')
                    return(Athelete(templ.pop(0), templ.pop(0), templ)
            except IOError as err:
                print("File Error: " + str(err))
                return(None)
#Sanitize function removes the '-(dash)',':(colon)' from the list and #replaces
#them with a 'period' so that using sorted BIF becomes possible
        def sanitize(self, time_list):
            sanitized=[]#a new list to store the end result
                for each_element in time_list:
                    if '-' in each_element:
                        splitter='-'
                    elif ':' in each_element:
                        splitter=':'
                    else:
                        splitter='.'
                    (mins, secs)=each_element.split(splitter) 
#using split to remove the '-',':'   '''
                    sanitized.append(mins + '.' + secs)
#then joining the items from lists mins and secs 
            return(sanitized)
#returning the sanitized list that is without the unwanted bits.
```

i am getting an error at the "except IOError as err" line saying invalid syntax.
i am using default IDLE for this if that makes any sense..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are missing a closing parenthesis on the line:

```
return(Athelete(templ.pop(0), templ.pop(0), templ)

                                                  ^
```

Comment: yes that indeed was the problem..! I couln't have spotted that ..so thank you very much..

Comment: @Samarth usually if you get a Syntax Error and the line shown doesn't make sense look a line before that. It's usually a missing parenthesis.